# Subcaptions without subfigures

Tags: captions, subcaption

I'm laying out a document that includes images that are made up of a series of sub images and each image includes labels directly in the image itself.  Here's an example ...

[image: Single PNG]

Again, the above is not 6 separate PNG files, but 1 PNG.

I need to caption the image ... I'd prefer to use something like `subcaption` to keep the formatting consistent for all the images in the document.

Currently I'm captioning the figure like this :

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,
            labelfont=bf, 
            labelsep=endash, 
            justification=RaggedRight]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig.png}
    \caption[My Figure]{\textbf{Myfigure (a)} This describes something shown in a. \textbf{(b)} This describes something shown in b. \textbf{(c)} This describes something shown in c. \textbf{(d)} This describes something shown in d. \textbf{(e)} This describes something shown in e. \textbf{(f)} This describes something shown in f.}
    \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to keep the code compact and to keep the formatting consistent, I'd prefer to use something like the `subcaption` package.  Syntax might look like this ...

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,
            labelfont=bf, 
            labelsep=endash, 
            justification=RaggedRight]{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=parens,
            labelsep=space]{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig.png}
    \caption[My Figure]{My Figure} \subcaption{This describes something shown in a.} \subcaption{This describes something shown in b.} \subcaption{This describes something shown in c.} \subcaption{This describes something shown in d.} \subcaption{This describes something shown in e.} \subcaption{This describes something shown in f.}
    \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Using subcaption]

This, however, has 2 issues ...

1. The compiler complains because `subcaption` is not in the correct environment.
2. There is a line break between the main caption title and each subcaption.

Is there any way to achieve a caption like the one in the first example but without having to brute force it the way the first example does?

Comment: Both \subcaption and \caption use the same \@makecaption, which takes up the entire width of the page (or minipage).

Answer (score 3):

Figure 5 from the subcaption documentation gives an example which can be adjusted to your situation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,
            labelfont=bf, 
            labelsep=endash, 
            justification=RaggedRight]{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=parens,
            labelsep=space]{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    {
    \phantomsubcaption\label{figa}
    \phantomsubcaption\label{figb}
        \phantomsubcaption\label{figc}
        \phantomsubcaption\label{figd}
        \phantomsubcaption\label{fige}
        \phantomsubcaption\label{figf}
        }
    \caption[My Figure]{My Figure (\subref{figa}) This describes something shown in a. (\subref{figb}) This describes something shown in b. (\subref{figc}) This describes something shown in c.(\subref{figd}) This describes something shown in d.(\subref{fige}) This describes something shown in e.(\subref{figf}) This describes something shown in f.}
    \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works but one question ... I was expecting the `labelfont=bf` option to be inherited from `caption` but it doesn't seem to make (a), (b), etc. bold.  I tried adding it to the sub-caption options but it also doesn't seem to work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Actually, this interestingly doesn't seem to respect any of the options of `subcaption` and the parentheses are hard coded.

Comment: @agf1997 It respects all options of subcaption for *referencing* the sublabels.

Answer (score 0):

This uses `\mycaption` to effect the formatting used in the first example.  Of course, all it really saves you is formatting the counter.

You can put a `\label` **inside** each `\mycaption`, if so inclined.  They should not interfere with the main caption `\label`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,
            labelfont=bf, 
            labelsep=endash, 
            justification=RaggedRight]{caption}

\newcounter{subfigure}[figure]% or install subcaption package
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}% format for \ref
\newcommand{\mycaption}[1]% #1 = text
{\bgroup
  \refstepcounter{subfigure}% global counter, local label
  \textbf{(\alph{subfigure})}~#1
 \egroup}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}% otherwise starts at (g)
    \caption[My Figure]{\textbf{Myfigure} 
      \mycaption{This describes something shown in a.} 
      \mycaption{This describes something shown in b.}
      \mycaption{This describes something shown in c.}
      \mycaption{This describes something shown in d.}
      \mycaption{This describes something shown in e.}
      \mycaption{This describes something shown in f.}}
    \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]