# Link text and figures including subplots

Tags: links, ref, hyperlink, subfig

I have a figure with many subplots created and labeled in Matlab. In the text of the tex file, I need to refer to each subplot separately e.g. 1a) 1b)..., nevertheless I can obviously link only the entire figure e.g. 1 in the text. How can I include the letters in the link? So far I have only changed the color of the letters manually, but I would also like to have the link if I go with the cursor above the letter.

For example I have a figure with three subplots and I need to discuss the first one:

```
\documentclass[%
reprint,
superscriptaddress,
amsmath,amssymb,
aps,
prb,
]{revtex4-2}

\hypersetup{
        colorlinks   = true,
        citecolor    = blue,
        linkcolor    = blue}

\begin{document} 


\begin{figure}[t]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{img.eps}
 \caption{(a) subplot1 (b) subplot2  (c) subplot3}
 \label{fig:figure}
 \end{figure}

Figure \ref{fig:figure}{\color{blue}{(a)}

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi, welcome. The `subcaption` package has a `\phantomsubcaption` command that can be used for such things. See an example at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/497598/

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  You should provide a minimal working example for us to copy and paste; it makes it much easier to help you.  Remember the `draft` option if your problem includes images.

Comment: My personal style (determined after hundreds of such cases) is to always create the smallest component figures separately and use tabular to lay them out, along with individual captions.

Comment: \phantomsubcaption works fine for my problem. Nevertheless I am using floatrow package that does not cooperate with subcaption package. I do not know how to create sidecaption in the subcaption environment..

Comment: \hyperref[<label>]{<arbitrary text>} was the solution...you are not so smart !

Comment: A couple of tips: 1) don't insult people if you want them to help you. At the time I posted my first comment I had no way of knowing how your document was set up, so I couldn't possibly know that you were using `revtex` and `floatrow`. 2) Only you as the owner of the post is notified of all comments. If you want to direct a comment at another user, write an `@` followed by the username, e.g. @mickeymar. When you start typing the username, a small box will appear with the name, you can then hit the Tab-key to autocomplete the name. 3) Consider posting an actual answer.