# How to make subfigure letter (a, b, c, ...) colorful in the text as referenced figures?

Tags: floats

The figures appear colorful when I refer them in the text:

See: [image]

However, the subfigures a & b are not real/automated subfigures. They are belong to 1 figure, I type a and be manually. I want the text also pretend like the Fig. 15a all part of it.

So I want to link "a" to the figure and also at the same color, when it is print of non-print mode.

```
%% Use TU Delft cyan as the color for titles, unless the 'print' option is
%% specified, in which case we use anthracite, a dark gray, which is also used
%% for the thumb indices.
\definecolor{anthracite}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.8}
\if@print
    \colorlet{title}{anthracite}
\else
    \colorlet{title}{tudelft-cyan}
   %\colorlet{title}{tudelft-cyan}
\fi
    \colorlet{thumb}{anthracite}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the subfigure environment (from the `subcaption` package) to make the labels automatically?

Comment: @Bernard Because there is indeed only one figure.

Comment: But subfigures are nested in a single figure, usually!

Comment: @Bernard but I have only one file as a figure

Comment: Do you mean you include a single graphic file for the  two subfigures?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, there is indeed only one graphic file. The subfigures are not there for the latex but they are on our minds :)

Comment: Can't you split it into two files with some graphic software?  It would  be much simpler.

Comment: @Bernard That could be a convenient solution, but there are ~50 figures like that.

Comment: Try using \phantomsubcaption, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497597/subcaptions-without-subfigures/

Answer (score 1):

You could add empty subcaption boxes to your figure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{hidden}{}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=hidden}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subcaptionbox{\label{a}}{}%
\subcaptionbox{\label{b}}{}%
anything

\caption{somecaption}
\end{figure}

\ref{a}, \ref{b}
\end{document}
```

[image]